# Multiple commands inside a terminal script

Tags: terminal

Good Day,

I am hoping to run a command to run a program, then run a command inside it via a shell script.

I want to run telnet localhost 4000, then inside that program's input, I want to run another bunch of commands.

Is this possible?

Raaj

Comment: Which platform are you running telnet on? And which version? Different systems have different capabilities. The answer to your question is yes, or perhaps no, depending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If Unix-Like

assuming a semi capable bourne shell descendent...

'here document' - read up on it:

```
 telnet localhost 4000 <<EOF
   cmda
   cmdb
 EOF
```

EOF can't be indented at all

#### If Windows

Put the commands in a file. c:\tmp\example.txt

```
telnet localhost 4000 < c:\tmp\example.txt
```

#### Else

I expect you'd know the need to specify your OS!

Comment: Where did you see that OP use Unix like platform ?

Comment: @sputnick hence the assuming line I added prior to seeing this, but yes, you're quite right

Comment: i tried this but it did not work. gave me such strange error:
Loading
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying fe80::1...
telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
and it never loaded the commands inside

Answer (score 0):

For *nix OS you can try expect scripts
http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Comment: No need expect scripts to feed telnet ! It's like a bazooka to kill a fly.